# Caliburn.Micro Action doesn't work

Tags: wpf, slider, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application with Caliburn.Micro.

I want to handle slider's move, i.e. MouseUp event.

```
<Slider cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp] = [Action OnSliderMouseUp($this)]"  
        Value="{Binding  PlayerPosition, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="200" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Minimum="0" 
        Maximum="{Binding Player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds}"/>
```

In ViewModel:

```
public void OnSliderMouseUp(Slider slider)
{
    int blah = 9;
}
```

`OnSliderMouseUp()` is never called. Could you please tell what I am missing?

Comment: Have you wired your view and viewmodel with Caliburn? How do you set the DataContext to your viewmodel? Try adding `cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding}"` to your `Slider` if it solves your problem it means your DataContext is not correctly wired with Caliburn

Comment: I follow the naming convention, so I assume the DataContext is the ViewModel. I added the code you suggested, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you have two problems:

1. The `Slider` control does not fires the `MouseUp` event. If you interested in an event which fires when the user stops dragging the slider you are looking for the [Thumb.DragCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb.dragcompleted.aspx).
   You can find more info here: [WPF: Slider with an event that triggers after a user drags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723502/wpf-slider-with-an-event-that-triggers-after-a-user-drags)
2. But if you whould write

   ```
   <Slider cal:Message.Attach="[Event Thumb.DragCompleted] = [Action OnSliderMouseUp($this)]"  />
   ```

   it still won't work. Because Caliburn.Micro (to be preciese `System.Windows.Interactiviy.EventTrigger` which is used by Calibrun.Micro) does not support attached events. For more info and a workaround see: [using attached events with caliburn micro Message.Attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402339/using-attached-events-with-caliburn-micro-message-attach)

So a working soultion (with the `RoutedEventTrigger` implementation from the above mentioned question):

```
<Slider Value="{Binding  PlayerPosition, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="200" ...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>                
        <local:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="Thumb.DragCompleted">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="OnSliderMouseUp">
                <cal:Parameter Value="$source" />
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </local:RoutedEventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Slider>
```

Note that because `Thumb.DragCompleted` an attached event `$this` won't work and you need to use **$source** instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The execution now comes to the handler, but the parameter is null. Could you tell why it is so? Thanks.

Comment: I've also realized that and updated my answer see the note at the end. You need use `$source` instead of `$this` (or $eventArgs and get the slider form the `DragComplatedEventArgs`'s `Source` property)

Comment: Strange it works for me with `$source`. Please try it with `$eventArgs` but in this case your method should look like: `OnSliderMouseUp(DragCompletedEventArgs args)` then the `args.Source` should contain your slider. If not then please post it what is inside the `args.Source` and `args.OriginalSource`

Comment: what is `i:` namespace and `local:` namespace?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary i is `xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
` local is your own namespace where you have your `RoutedEventTrigger` implementation described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402339/using-attached-events-with-caliburn-micro-message-attach