# Validation.Error Attached event with caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

The following works and ErrorHandler in my code behind is called.

XAML :

```
 <Window Validation.Error="ErrorHandler">   

  <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SomeProperty" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <local:MyValidationRule />
        </Binding>
     </TextBox.Text>
  </TextBox>

  </Window>
```

CS:

```
  private void ErrorHandler(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
  {
             ............ 
  }
```

Now i would like to transfer that to my ViewModel using Caliburn Micro's **Message.Attach** 
The delegated method is never called, any idea why ?

XAML :

```
 <Window cal:Message.Attach="[Event Validation.Error] = [Action OnErrorsChanged($eventArgs)]">   

  <TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SomeProperty" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <local:MyValidationRule />
     </Binding>
     </TextBox.Text>
  </TextBox>

  </Window>
```

CS: (In My ViewModel)

```
  private void OnErrorsChanged(ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
  {
       ............ this code is never reached.
  }
```

Edit :  This also doesn't work

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Validation.Error">
         <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="OnErrorsChanged" />         
     </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do `Validation.Error` as Caliburn.Micro might not find it. Not sure if the attached properties is supported when doing `Message.Attach`.

Comment: i'm not sure either ..

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? Why you wanna handle ErrorsChanged?

Comment: yes , but the validation error is raised from inner workings of a custom control in my view , it has nothing to do with any property in my ViewModel , all i wan't is to notify my ViewModel that Validation.Error event was raised and pass the args, i can think of ways to do this but i hoped this simple way to work.

Comment: May be something of use here: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/243212 or here: http://www.redmountainsw.com/wordpress/2012/12/21/tutorial-validating-data-with-caliburn-micro/ or this chap's fixed sample: https://github.com/tibel/Caliburn.Micro.Extras/tree/master/samples/Samples.Validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it seems that I found the answer

[using attached events with caliburn micro Message.Attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402339/using-attached-events-with-caliburn-micro-message-attach)

This is not exactly what you are looking for. But I belive, this should help.

EDIT:

Another one additional trick. Here is my code snippet:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2"  >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ui:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="Validation.ValidationError">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="OnTextboxError">
                <cal:Parameter Value="$source" />
                <cal:Parameter Value="$eventArgs" />
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </ui:RoutedEventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="TTT" NotifyOnValidationError="True" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ui:TextValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>


public void OnTextboxError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{

}
```

So the trick is: "RoutedEvent="Validation.ValidationError""

Comment: I'm actually not using that any more , WPF validation's well i'll use the word Suck.
but thanks i believe what you've done would work , all the problems with Message.Attach seem to occur using the Shorted syntax.

Comment: I'm agree with you. It's some kind of delirium. I had spent couple of days to determine why does textbox validation works " almost well", but datagrid column validation doesn't works in proper way. More over, each new knowladge I get will be useless for next task.